# How can I process images?

Tags: java, image, process, pixel

I want to make a program which takes a image and makes on it nice effects. The effects is like blur or something like this, and i think I know theoretically how to do it, but I don't know how to get to the image data and practically change it and than save a entirely new image.

I know that every image made of pixels and which one of them have is own color. My question is how can I load the image text source(?) or how can I get the information about the image pixels, then change this information and saved this data as a new image.
I'm using java.

Comment: *"i want to make a program"*  Do you want to find your shift key and apply it at the start of every sentence to make your words easier to read?  I am not prepared to read your 'mumbling'.

Answer (score 3):

[BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) is what you are looking for. You can create `BufferedImage` instances from reading images from the filesystem (or other locations) using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../images/exmaple.jpg"));

// get red/green/blue/alpha value for pixel at position (10,20)
int rgb = image.getRGB(10, 20);
```

Changing values can be done using `setRGB()`. The updated image can then be saved to a file using `ImageIO.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check ImageFilter and subclasses (e.g. BufferedImageFilter). Depending on the required outputformat you might need an external lib to save the image after transforming.